# Atmospheric correction on Landsat scene using Python

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, dark-object-subtraction

I need to develop a workflow to analyze Landsat and Sentinel 2 scenes using **Python** and **Xarray** library. Generally I do this task using QGIS and Semi Automatic Classification Plugin, I'm using the output from the plugin to verify my analysis with Python.
Now I'm working on Landsat 8 scene(LC08_L1TP_189032_20210617_20210622_02_T1) and, following the indication from the [plugin documentation](https://semiautomaticclassificationmanual-v3.readthedocs.io/uk_UA/latest/remote_sensing.html#landsat-conversion-to-reflectance), I've computed the spectral radiance. After this calculation I will use DOS1 for compute the land surface reflectance.

For compute spectral radiance I've used the formula below:

[image]

*Qcal* is the L1C raw product's DN, *Ml* and *Al* comes from `MTL` file, for band 2 they are:

- Radiance multiplicative scaling factor: 1.2518E-02;
- Radiance additive scaling factor: -62.59149.

So, now I've the spectral radiance at sensor and comes my problems, I think they are caused to dark object subtraction. Below the formula for compute the land surface reflectance with **DOS1**:
[image]

Where:

- *d* is the sun earth distance(in this case 1.0143229);
- *ESUN* is the mean solar exo-atmospheric irradiances;

> [image]

- Radiance maximum from `MTL`:  -62.57897;
- Reflectance maximum from `MTL`: 1.210700;
- *θs* is the sun zenith angle(90° - sun elevation[65.54618618°]);
- *Lλ* is the spectral radiance previously computated:
- *Lp* is the path radiance based on DOS.

Below the formula for compute path radiance:

[image]

Where:

- *LDO1%* is the radiance of dark object that is very simple to calcuate with DOS1 because the value for *Tv* and *Tz* is 1 and the value for *Edown* is 0;

> [image]

- *Lmin* is

> radiance that corresponds to a digital count value for which the sum of all the pixels with digital counts lower or equal to this value is equal to the 0.01% of all the pixels from the image considered.
> [image]

Until now most of the effort is focused on "re-use" of `MTL`'s data, my doubts and problems comes when I compute *DNmin*. I understood that DNmin is not the minimum of DN, (I used`xarray.DataArray.min`) and googling I found [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/353909/72195) that explane my same problem but on Sentinel 2's scenes. He says that his formula returns values not quite different from the output of QGIS's plugin but it is not true in my case because I see values ​​from 2 to 7 times greater using his formula.

There is another approach to compute land surface radiance? A specific library for Python is fine too.

I'm be able to compute the atmospheric reflectance using the formula on the plugin's documentation with Python. My output is quite similar to the plugin's output, there is a difference of 9% but I think it depend on the rounding problems because my result has 18 decimal places and the result from plugin has only 4.